# Dynamically resizing cell with a tableView within it (iOS)

Tags: ios, dynamic, resize

I have a tableView, and within each UITableViewCell (call this parentCell), I have another tableView which has cells (call this childCell).  I am using UITableViewAutomaticDimension to dynamically resize both of the cells height.  I am successfully able to resize the height of the childCell this way, however, I am not able to apply UITableViewAutomaticDimension to the parentCell, since there when heightForRow is called, the childCell's height have yet to be estimated.

Is it possible to use UITableViewAutomaticDimension to estimate the parent cells height, which will be the height of all the childCell's height added together?  Or am I going to have to do this manually?

```
//in ViewDidLoad
parentTableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension

//in ParentCell's tableView's cell for row
cell.childTableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to do this was to use sections instead of placing a tableview within a cell.